# Save screenshot with overlay image OpenGLES

Tags: ios, opengl-es, uiimageview, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm using vuforia for Augmented Reality applciation. When i detect image i can able display or render 3D object and UIImageView then i can take the screenshot of 3D object but i can't save the normal image. I'm just displaying normal UIImageview holding of images. Do i need to render 2D image instead of normal UIImageView?

Render 3D:

```
- (void)renderFrameQCAR
{
    [self setFramebuffer];

    // Clear colour and depth buffers
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Render video background and retrieve tracking state
    QCAR::State state = QCAR::Renderer::getInstance().begin();
    QCAR::Renderer::getInstance().drawVideoBackground();

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    // We must detect if background reflection is active and adjust the culling direction.
    // If the reflection is active, this means the pose matrix has been reflected as well,
    // therefore standard counter clockwise face culling will result in "inside out" models.
    if (offTargetTrackingEnabled) {
        glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    } else {
        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    }
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    if(QCAR::Renderer::getInstance().getVideoBackgroundConfig().mReflection == QCAR::VIDEO_BACKGROUND_REFLECTION_ON)
        glFrontFace(GL_CW);  //Front camera
    else
        glFrontFace(GL_CCW);   //Back camera


    for (int i = 0; i < state.getNumTrackableResults(); ++i) {
        // Get the trackable

       // _numResults = state.getNumTrackableResults();
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(DisplayPhotoButton
                                                    ) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

        const QCAR::TrackableResult* result = state.getTrackableResult(i);
        const QCAR::Trackable& trackable = result->getTrackable();

        //const QCAR::Trackable& trackable = result->getTrackable();
        QCAR::Matrix44F modelViewMatrix = QCAR::Tool::convertPose2GLMatrix(result->getPose());

        // OpenGL 2
        QCAR::Matrix44F modelViewProjection;

        if (offTargetTrackingEnabled) {
            SampleApplicationUtils::rotatePoseMatrix(90, 1, 0, 0,&modelViewMatrix.data[0]);
            SampleApplicationUtils::scalePoseMatrix(kObjectScaleOffTargetTracking, kObjectScaleOffTargetTracking, kObjectScaleOffTargetTracking, &modelViewMatrix.data[0]);
        } else {
            SampleApplicationUtils::translatePoseMatrix(0.0f, 0.0f, kObjectScaleNormal, &modelViewMatrix.data[0]);
            SampleApplicationUtils::scalePoseMatrix(kObjectScaleNormal, kObjectScaleNormal, kObjectScaleNormal, &modelViewMatrix.data[0]);
        }

        SampleApplicationUtils::multiplyMatrix(&vapp.projectionMatrix.data[0], &modelViewMatrix.data[0], &modelViewProjection.data[0]);

        glUseProgram(shaderProgramID);

        if (offTargetTrackingEnabled) {
            glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)buildingModel.vertices);
            glVertexAttribPointer(normalHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)buildingModel.normals);
            glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordHandle, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)buildingModel.texCoords);
        } else {
            glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)teapotVertices);
            glVertexAttribPointer(normalHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)teapotNormals);
            glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordHandle, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)teapotTexCoords);
        }

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalHandle);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);

        // Choose the texture based on the target name
        int targetIndex = 0; // "stones"
        if (!strcmp(trackable.getName(), "chips"))
            targetIndex = 1;
        else if (!strcmp(trackable.getName(), "tarmac"))
            targetIndex = 2;

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);

        if (offTargetTrackingEnabled) {
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, augmentationTexture[3].textureID);
        } else {
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, augmentationTexture[targetIndex].textureID);
        }
        glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixHandle, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat*)&modelViewProjection.data[0]);
        glUniform1i(texSampler2DHandle, 0 /*GL_TEXTURE0*/);

        if (offTargetTrackingEnabled) {
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, buildingModel.numVertices);
        } else {
            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, NUM_TEAPOT_OBJECT_INDEX, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (const GLvoid*)teapotIndices);
        }

        SampleApplicationUtils::checkGlError("EAGLView renderFrameQCAR");

    }

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(normalHandle);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);

    QCAR::Renderer::getInstance().end();
    [self presentFramebuffer];
}
```

Display UIImageView when cameraview open:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame appSession:(SampleApplicationSession *) app
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {
        vapp = app;

      //  takePhotoFlag = NO;


        // [self DisplayPhotoButton];

        // Enable retina mode if available on this device
        if (YES == [vapp isRetinaDisplay]) {
            [self setContentScaleFactor:2.0f];
        }

        // Load the augmentation textures
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_AUGMENTATION_TEXTURES; ++i) {
            augmentationTexture[i] = [[Texture alloc] initWithImageFile:[NSString stringWithCString:textureFilenames[i] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
        }

        // Create the OpenGL ES context
        context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

        // The EAGLContext must be set for each thread that wishes to use it.
        // Set it the first time this method is called (on the main thread)
        if (context != [EAGLContext currentContext]) {
            [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
        }

        // Generate the OpenGL ES texture and upload the texture data for use
        // when rendering the augmentation
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_AUGMENTATION_TEXTURES; ++i) {
            GLuint textureID;
            glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
            [augmentationTexture[i] setTextureID:textureID];
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
            glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, [augmentationTexture[i] width], [augmentationTexture[i] height], 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*)[augmentationTexture[i] pngData]);
        }

        offTargetTrackingEnabled = NO;

        [self loadBuildingsModel];
        [self initShaders];


        _takePhotoFlag = NO;


        [self DisplayPhotoButton];



    }

    return self;
}


- (void)DisplayPhotoButton

{




    UIImage *closeButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];
    // UIImage *closeButtonTappedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_close_pressed.png"];



    CGRect aRect = CGRectMake(20,20,

                              closeButtonImage.size.width,
                              closeButtonImage.size.height);

    photo = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    photo.frame = aRect;

    photo.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

    [photo setImage:closeButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    // photo.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;

    [photo addTarget:self action:@selector(takePhoto) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self  addSubview:photo];



    UIButton *arrowButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [arrowButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // [overlayButton setFrame:CGRectMake(80, 420, 60, 30)];

    [arrowButton setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 10, 40, 40)];

    [arrowButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showActionSheet:forEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:arrowButton];

}
```

OpenGL screenshot:

```
    - (UIImage*) glToUIImage

    {

              UIImage *outputImage = nil;

            CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
            CGRect s = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0f * scale, 480.0f * scale);
            uint8_t *buffer = (uint8_t *) malloc(s.size.width * s.size.height * 4);

            glReadPixels(0, 0, s.size.width, s.size.height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

 UIImage *imageFromRawData(uint8_t *data, int width, int height) {
        CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL,data,width*height*4,NULL);

        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 32, width*4, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), kCGImageAlphaLast, provider, NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

        UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
        return newImage;
    }

            CGDataProviderRef ref = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer, s.size.width * s.size.height * 4, NULL);

            CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(s.size.width, s.size.height, 8, 32, s.size.width * 4, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault, ref, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

            size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(iref);
            size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(iref);
            size_t length = width * height * 4;
            uint32_t *pixels = (uint32_t *)malloc(length);

            CGContextRef context1 = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, width, height, 8, width * 4,
                                                          CGImageGetColorSpace(iref), kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

            CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0f, height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);
            CGContextConcatCTM(context1, transform);
            CGContextDrawImage(context1, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, width, height), iref);
            CGImageRef outputRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context1);

            outputImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: outputRef];

            CGDataProviderRelease(ref);
            CGImageRelease(iref);
            CGContextRelease(context1);
            CGImageRelease(outputRef);
            free(pixels);
            free(buffer);

            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputImage, nil, nil, nil);
            return outputImage;


        }
```

Save from present frame buffer:

```
- (BOOL)presentFramebuffer
{


    if (_takePhotoFlag)

    {

        [self glToUIImage];


        _takePhotoFlag = NO;

    }


    // setFramebuffer must have been called before presentFramebuffer, therefore
    // we know the context is valid and has been set for this (render) thread

    // Bind the colour render buffer and present it
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);

    return [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either have an openGL screenshot or UI screenshot. To combine the 2 I suggest you to do both images. This will sound silly but it is probably the fastest and most powerful way to do this:

- Take a screenshot from openGL (as you already do)
- Create an image view from that screenshot
- Insert that image view on your main view
- Take an UI screenshot* of the main view
- Remove the image view

*By UI screenshot I mean something like this:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageFromView:(UIView *)view {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, .0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```

If you will have an issue such as seeing black background instead of the background image there is probably an issue generating the `CGImage` somewhere in the pipeline where it is skipping or premultiplying the alpha channel. (a very common mistake)

EDIT: Getting image from read pixels RGBA data:

This is what I used for getting an `UIImage` from raw RGBA data. Note this procedure will not handle any orientation but you can modify it a bit take the orientation as an argument as well and then use `imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:`

```
UIImage *imageFromRawData(uint8_t *data, int width, int height) {
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL,data,width*height*4,NULL);

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 32, width*4, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), kCGImageAlphaLast, provider, NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was talking about: kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst skips the alpha channel, try using kCGImageAlphaLast (or first?). Might be best if you try to save the GL screenshot image to some file to debug this settings. It must be transparent where no shape is drawn...

Comment: Edited to add image generation from raw RGBA data.

Comment: I didn't understand. Can you please check my edited code. I'm taking screenshot from presentFramebuffer'

Comment: What part don't you understand? You can call the method I posted right after you call read pixels with parameters: buffer, s.size.width, s.size.height .

Comment: Do i need to change whole code? Where change in my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54778/discussion-between-user3602987-and-matic-oblak).

Comment: Can you check my openGL screenshot. I'm getting error